# Requests to YouTube API using asyncio and aiohttp, always freezing at task number 101

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Im trying to get details about youtube videos based on their IDs. I have a list of 40k IDs and i divide it to list of lists containing 50 ids, since yt api can handle 50 ids at once.

My code just freezes at task number 101.

```
import asyncio
import time
import aiohttp
from aiohttp.client import ClientSession
import requests

results = []
chunks = [click the link for IDs]

start = time.time()

def get_tasks(session):
    tasks = []
    for x in range(len(chunks)):
        params = {'key': 'yourapikey',
                  'part': 'statistics,contentDetails,snippet',
                  'id': chunks[x]
                  }
        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos"
        tasks.append(session.get(url=url, params=params, ssl=False))
        # print(x)
        print(len(tasks))
    return tasks

async def get_data():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session)
        print("len ", len(tasks))
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            results.append(await response.json())

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

asyncio.run(get_data())
print(time.time() - start)
```

I'm not sure what is happening here, how can i debug this problem?
Link to the chunks lists:

https://justpaste.it/8gwq6

Comment: YouTube may be rate limiting you - just waiting a short while may be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you had errors, I just know if you do it like below, you wont have errors (as long as your params are correct). In essence, we are just taking [this example](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/#client-example) from `aiohttp` docs, sticking the `session` part in a loop, and modifying the response for your needs.

```
import asyncio, aiohttp, ssl, certifi, requests, random, time

CHROME = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
          'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')

SSL_CONTEXT           = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
HEADERS               = requests.utils.default_headers()
HEADERS['User-Agent'] = random.choice(CHROME)
URL                   = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos"


start  = time.time()
chunks = [["Ul3w34H-byY", "OJdiW61Q9bM"], ["R3En-aLGwhw", "nrwXOn1rITY"]]
params = {'key' : 'APIKEY',
          'part': 'statistics,contentDetails,snippet'}

async def get_data():   
    results = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=HEADERS) as session:
        for chunk in chunks:
            params['id'] = chunk
            async with session.get(url=URL, params=params, ssl=SSL_CONTEXT) as resp:
                if not (resp.status==200): continue
                results.append(await resp.json())

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

asyncio.run(get_data())
print(time.time() - start)
```